# C++ 2D Array Arithmetic Issue

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I've been working with C++ long enough to attempt to build a somewhat simple tic-tac-toe game.   Players take turns adding 1's and 2's to a dynamically sized game board by supplying the desired element.

The functions provided to decide the player's turn and game-board update work o.k., but the code below which checks the board represented by 0's for a winning condition such as:

- 3 adjacent 1's and 2's
- 3 vertically aligned 1's and 2's
- 3 diagonal 1's and 2's

Does not work however. When tested, the board is simply updated every turn.  The problem I suspect is the array arithmetic.  How can the arithmetic be implemented to successfully detect the conditions?  Thanks in advance.

```
bool chkCondition(int rows, int columns, int**board){
int counter=0;
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j]+1==1 && board[i][j]+2==1){//checks horizontally for 1
            cout << "Player 1 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j]+columns==1 && board[i][j]+2*columns==1){//checks vertically for 1
            cout << "Player 1 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j]+columns+1==1 && board[i][j]+2*columns+2==1){//checks diagonally for 1
            cout << "Player 1 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j]+1==2 && board[i][j]+2==2){//checks horizontally for 2
            cout << "Player 2 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j]+columns==2 && board[i][j]+2*columns==2){//checks vertically for 2
            cout << "Player 2 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j]+columns+1==2 && board[i][j]+2*columns+2==2){//checks diagonally for 2 
            cout << "Player 2 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==0){//attempts to detect if the game is a draw
            if(counter==(rows+columns)-3){
                cout << "It's a draw!";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
counter++;
}
```

**Edit**
The arithmetic was changed to its correct format to find elements rather than add their values.  The new code is here:

```
bool chkCondition(int rows, int columns, int**board){
int counter=0;
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    counter++;
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+1]==1 && board[i][j+2]==1){
            cout << "Player 1 wins!";
            return true;
        }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j+1]==2 && board[i][j+2]==2){
            cout << "Player 2 wins!";
            return true;
        }
        if(counter==rows | counter>rows-1){
            //cout << "L--------\n";
            //cout << "checking vertical\n";
            if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j-columns]==1 && board[i][j-columns-columns]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j-columns]==2 && board[i][j-columns-columns]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            //cout << "checking diagonal\n";
            }else if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j-columns-1]==1 && board[i][j-columns-columns-2]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j-columns-1]==2 && board[i][j-columns-columns-2]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(counter==1 && counter<rows-1){
            //cout << "H--------\n";
            //cout << "checking vertical\n";
            if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+columns]==1 && board[i][j+columns+columns]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j+columns]==2 && board[i][j+columns+columns]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            //cout << "checking diagonal\n";
            }else if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+columns+1]==1 && board[i][j+columns+columns+2]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j+columns+1]==2 && board[i][j+columns+columns+2]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(counter>2 && counter<rows-1){
            //cout << "M--------\n";
            //cout << "checking vertical\n";
            if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+columns]==1 && board[i][j-columns]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j+columns]==2 && board[i][j-columns]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            //cout << "checking diagonal\n";
            }else if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+columns+1]==1 && board[i][j-columns-1]==1){
                cout << "Player 1 wins!";
                return true;
            }else if(board[i][j]==2 && board[i][j+columns+1]==2 && board[i][j-columns-1]==2){
                cout << "Player 2 wins!";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

}

The outer if statements are used to determine if the counter which counts the current row in the iteration whether it is at the beginning, middle or end of the table to avoid a segmentation fault. This works and the program doesn't crash, However, all the vertical and diagonal conditional statements do not work at all though the arithmetic is logical.  Can anybody tell what's going on?

Comment: It's not totally clear from your code/question; Do you mean for values such as ``board[i][j]+columns==1`` to do what they actually do, which is take the value at ``board[i][j]`` and then add ``columns`` to it and compare to ``==1``, or do you mean them to do something different. I assume the latter, but always good to ask for clarification in case, since you do it so many times.

Comment: I am attempting to say "if you detect 1 on the board, compare it to the one next to you and the one after that".  If it passes, then the message is sent and it returns true.  **Edit** this is for the first if statement: if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j]+1==1 (i.e. the one nest to board[i][j] && board[i][j]+2==1(the one next to board[i][j]+1).

Comment: `board[i][j]+1`  This takes the value located at `board[i][j]` plus 1.  This does not take the value located at `board[i][j+1]`.  For something as simple as this, maybe you should review carefully how to properly denote positions in an array.

Comment: I did test this with a simple program in another project:int a[2];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;

    cout << a[0+1] << endl; -> gave 2, the added value in a[0] right?
    cout << a[0] + 2 << "\n"; -> gave 3, the index pointed to by a[0] + 2 right?

Comment: Nope. In your example a[0+1] gives you a[1] which is 2. a[0] + 2 gives you 1 + 2 which is 3

Comment: Cool, thanks guys.  I guess I was too hasty with such a simple "one or the other" kind of problem.

Comment: Also, you're going in your loop through all the cells, so you can fall out of range when doing `board[i][j+1]`

Comment: I just updated the code, works beautifully, thanks!  I'll keep that in mind also ionagamed.  So how does the point system work, like am i supposed to give them out and award the post that solved the problem to close the Question?

Comment: @cfritz nobody posted an answer yet; this question should probably be closed as "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said, the problem is how you access the table. The other problem is how you use the loop. If you're checking horizontally first then your loop goes to every line but shouldn't go to every column or you'll get a nice segmentation fault.
For example the first part (assuming you actually put the +1/+2 at the good place

```
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if(board[i][j]==1 && board[i][j+1]==1 && board[i][j+2]==1){//checks horizontally for 1
            cout << "Player 1 wins!";
            return true;
```

It will give you a segmentation fault when j is either columns-2 or columns. To solve this you need to stop before in your second for. For checking horizontally it's the same with lines. It's more complicated to do only one loop like this or you need to add more ifs to avoid this error.

Comment: The game works well now, though the problem with the arithmetic not working finally came down to the pointer to a pointer array I was using to dynamically allocate memory.  The memory in a pointer array is non-contiguous so when the arithmetic [i][j+columns] was hit, regardless of whether it was correct, it could not find the rest of the array because it was stored somewhere else in memory.  I ended up scrapping the pointer and just put everything in main with a normal 2D array because I couldn't pass an uninitialized 2D array to any functions.

Comment: if you do it with `std::vector` it should be much easier and you can easily pass 2D arrays to functions (just do it by reference to avoid copy)